# How to show dialog when back pressed in few fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a secnerio where I need to show dialog when user press back button in fragment.I tried few ways but I couldn't able to find the solution. Can someone help on this

Comment: what did not help? show us some code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet? That will help us diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface

```
public interface OnBackPressedListener {
    void onBackPressed();
}
```

And implement it by your fragment. 
You need to show the dialog in your fragment's `onBackPressed()` method. And in your main activity override:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    if (currentFragment instanceof OnBackPressedListener)
        ((OnBackPressedListener) currentFragment).onBackPressed();
    else if (!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack())
        finish();    
}
```

Note that it is assumed that you will have only one fragment active at a time (you must always call `replace()` on the `fragmentManager`).

So, every time back button is pressed, your activity will check if your fragment wants to handle this press by itself, and if so, it will call its method for this.

If you have any questions feel free to ask in the comments.